# Pandas: Difference with first element of the group

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm attempting to calculate a date difference between elements in a group and the first element in the group.

Consider the following `pandas.DataFrame`, grouped by `operation#`, `type` and `date`:

```
                                    RATE    AMT       
OPR        TYPE     DATE RET                     
232        BUY      2012-02-16      1.005   3000023.02
           SELL     2012-07-02      1.005   3000023.02
235        BUY      2012-02-28      1.005   9900008.03
           SELL     2012-07-26      1.005   9900008.03
251        BUY      2012-01-13      0.990   5000000.00
           SELL     2012-04-11      0.990    200000.98
                    2012-04-20      0.990    300000.98
                    2012-04-26      0.990    700000.00
                    2012-08-17      0.990    100000.98
...        ...        ...            ...        ...
```

I would like to insert a Duration column (integer), defined as

```
Duration = Sell_Date - Buy_Date .
```

The only way I have managed to do this is with a very slow list comprehension that needs to filter the data frame for each step, which is not acceptable.

How can I calculate the difference between the SELL dates and the BUY date within the same OPR_NUM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` followed by `.transform`:

```
>>> def tranf(obj):
...     date_ret = obj.index.get_level_values('DATE RET')
...     return (date_ret - date_ret[0]).days
... 
>>> df['DURATION'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='int64')
>>> df['DURATION'] = df.groupby(level='OPR')['DURATION'].transform(tranf)
>>> df
                      RATE         AMT  DURATION
OPR TYPE DATE RET                               
232 BUY  2012-02-16  1.005  3000023.02         0
    SELL 2012-07-02  1.005  3000023.02       137
235 BUY  2012-02-28  1.005  9900008.03         0
    SELL 2012-07-26  1.005  9900008.03       149
251 BUY  2012-01-13  0.990  5000000.00         0
    SELL 2012-04-11  0.990   200000.98        89
         2012-04-20  0.990   300000.98        98
         2012-04-26  0.990   700000.00       104
         2012-08-17  0.990   100000.98       217
```

There are some problems with how `.transform` handles data-types; to avoid those problems I first add an integer column and then transform over that column even though I do not need its values.

Comment: Mostly works, but:
    *return (date_ret - date_ret[0]).days*
raises a TypeError.

I used:
    *return [(x-date_ret[0]).days for x in date_ret]*
instead.

Comment: @user2628744 you need to make sure `DATE RET` is date-time before making setting the index, something like `df['DATE RET'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE RET'])`